# update records with different table data in a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a issue like this is a loop of records coming from a table (trans) and in this loop there is a dropdown list of users coming from a table (users).

I want to update the driver column of table(trans) against every record from the table(users).. here is the code

```
$records = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trans WHERE (receiver = '".$receiver."' && cdate = '".$cdate."') ", $conn_str);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($records);
 }  

    elseif($count > "0"){echo  "<h3>" . $count . " - Records Found</h3>";}
      elseif($count < "0"){echo  "<h3 style='color:red'> NO Records Found</h3>";}

  if($records === FALSE) {die(mysql_error());}


if($count > 0){

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)) {
  echo "<tr class='records'>" ;
  echo "<td>"  .  $counter++ . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"  .  $row ['cust_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"  .  $row ['house'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"  .  $row ['street'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td style='text-transform:uppercase'>"  .  $row ['post_code'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"  .  $row ['cust_cellno'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"  .  $row ['bags'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"  .  $row ['remarks'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"  .  $row ['ref_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"  .  $row ['receiver'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"  .  $row ['cdate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"  .  $row ['collect_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"  .  $row ['type_of_call'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"  .  $row ['ctime'] . "</td>";
  ?>

<td>
<? $q = "SELECT username FROM ".DBTBLE." where user_level = '2' ";
    $drivers = mysql_query($q);
    $num_rows = mysql_numrows($drivers);    
     ?>

   <select name="Driver">
      <option>Select Driver</option>
      <? for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++){
      $name=mysql_result($drivers,$i,"username");
      echo "<option value=\"$name\">$name</option>";}?>
    </select>       
  </td>
```

this above dropdown list is basically from table(users).

```
<form method="post" name="update_form" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
  <input name="trans_id" type="text" id="trans_id" value="<? echo $trans_id; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="update_btn" class="update" value="Update">
</form>
<?
   if(isset($_POST['update_btn'])) {

  $update = mysql_query("UPDATE trans SET driver='$name' WHERE trans_id='". $row["trans_id"] ."'", $conn_str);
$retval = $update;

if($retval){
 echo "<center><h2>Booking Successfully Updated</h2></center>"; 
 }
   else {die('Could not update data:' . mysql_error());
   }
  }
?>
```

And there is no common field in both of the tables.

Comment: Errors if any? Are you checking for them besides DB errors?

Comment: Yes dear there are no errors i checked that

Comment: Is this in your pages? `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` not just `mysql_error()`; it isn't always enough.

Comment: *Plus*, if you don't have a custom function called `mysql_numrows()` then there's an error; it should be `mysql_num_rows()`; you missed an underscore. Also, I take it you have your constant `DBTBLE` already set?

Comment: Another probable contributing factor would be to make sure that short tags are ON. If doing `<? echo "Hello world"; ?>` works for you, great. If not, you'll need to change all `<?` to `<?php`. Short tags are often discouraged when populating from DB. You will need to continue [*debugging*](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php) your code.

Comment: Actually dropdown is working fine getting records but there is some problem in update query i think

Comment: on your update query $name variable value comes from where? Isn't that suppose to be posted along with your trans_id? and what is the result in trans table once you run your update query is it empty?

Comment: Yes in trans table the column is not updating but it's going through the code. showing successful message.

The $name variable is basically coming from dropdown list but dropdown is from different table in database.Yes the $name should be posted in trans table within column 'driver' with trans_id

Comment: Can you try var_dump() your update query and check if the $name variable value is there in your query... ?